# Need to convert datetime to date during D8 migration from non-drupal source

Tags: migrations

I'm working on a migration where I have

2012-05-07 00:00:00.000000

in my timedate field, but I need to convert it to:

2012-05-07

I realize that I should put this in the prepareRow function, but I'm not sure what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function prepareRow(Row $row) {

   $date = $row->getSourceProperty('database_date_field');
   $date = strtotime($date); // -> 1336341600 unix timestamp
   $date = date('Y-m-d', $date); // -> "2012-05-07"

   // Here you 'rewrite' the field with the new value before it gets saved
   $row->setSourceProperty('database_date_field', $date);
   return parent::prepareRow($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a format_date process plugin:

```
process:
  field_my_date:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    to_format: 'Y-m-d'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the source property containing that value is, say, "timestamp", then in prepareRow you can do:

```
$row->setSourceProperty('timestamp', strtok($row->getSourceProperty('timestamp'), ' '));
```